# how to handle when comma and double quotes altogether in CSV file while importing in Informatica

Tags: sql, csv, etl, informatica, informatica-cloud

I have vendor SQL table which column value as :

131 Maker Tower, "F", Premises

While exporting in CSV from Informatica , following value is   generated: ,

"131 Maker Tower, "F", Premises",

But when I read into the Informatica for importing into other table
using CSV : It just fails as it read this into 3 different columns as
comma is delimiter.

- Column 1: 131 Maker Tower
- Column 2: F
- Column3: Premises

We want to export such that it is readable to business so can't use complex delimiter like *, or || etc.

Answer (score 0):

If informatica is trying to read a file which looks like this,

```
"131 Maker Tower, "F", Premises",
```

then use below properties `optional quotes = Double Quote`

[image]

Now, if this doesnt work, (because i havent tested this with this many double quote inside a string). The workaround would be, when you read from your first process, create a new file with new delimiter(like pipe) for intoamtica only. This will not be used by business. You can use this as your source file - it will work smoothly.

Comment: The issue is we never if tomorrow pipe character or some other character might come in string column. At that time data might get wrongly loaded in DB.

Comment: agree, so use some combination of characters like `~|` as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wrong output. A right export for CSV is

```
"131 Maker Tower, ""F"", Premises"
```

If you import it, I think you will have only one field, containing `131 Maker Tower, "F", Premises`

Comment: IF i export like this :   ,"131 Maker Tower, ""F"", Premises", dont you think while importing it will break like this : Column 1 as  "131 Maker Tower, ""F"    and Column 2 as : Premises

Comment: @Goks if the importer is a right importer, it will import it properly. Try it